# Trying to implement an inference for a downloaded pretrained ESRGAN model

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I'm pretty nooby when it comes to PyTorch and DeepLearning, however I downloaded a pretrained ESRGAN model (4x_eula_digimanga_bw_v1_860k.pth) from https://upscale.wiki/wiki/Model_Database#Manga
and wanted to make it a run with a simple Python implementation which looks like this:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image

# Import the model definition from the "model_definition.py" file
from model_definition import RRDBBlock, ESRGANModel

# Load the ESRGAN model from the .pth file
model_path = "./models/4x_eula_digimanga_bw_v1_860k.pth"  # Replace "path_to_your_model_file.pth" with the actual file path
device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")

# Define the Residual in Residual Dense Block (RRDB) class
# ... (use the RRDBBlock implementation from "model_definition.py")

# Define the ESRGAN model class
# ... (use the ESRGANModel implementation from "model_definition.py")

# Load the model and weights separately
model_data = torch.load(model_path, map_location=device)
model_state_dict = model_data["model_state_dict"]

# Create an instance of the ESRGAN model
model = ESRGANModel()  # Replace "ESRGANModel" with the correct name of your model class
model.load_state_dict(model_state_dict)
model.to(device)
model.eval()

# Define a function for upscaling an image
def upscale_image(input_image_path, output_image_path):
    # Load the image
    image = Image.open(input_image_path).convert("RGB")

    # Convert the image to a tensor
    transform = transforms.ToTensor()
    image_tensor = transform(image).unsqueeze(0).to(device)

    # Upscale the image using the ESRGAN model
    with torch.no_grad():
        upscaled_image = model(image_tensor).clamp(0.0, 1.0)

    # Convert the tensor image back to a PIL image
    upscaled_image = transforms.ToPILImage()(upscaled_image.squeeze(0).cpu())

    # Save the upscaled image
    upscaled_image.save(output_image_path)

# Example: Paths to the input and output images
input_image_path = "./input/135.png"  # Replace "path_to_your_input_image.jpg" with the actual file path
output_image_path = "./output/135_US.png"  # Replace "path_to_your_output_image.jpg" with the actual file path

# Call the function to upscale the image
upscale_image(input_image_path, output_image_path)
```

Here's the model_definition.py I am importing, containing class definitions for the ESRGAN model as well as for RRDB:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Define the Residual in Residual Dense Block (RRDB) class
class RRDBBlock(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels, growth_rate=32, num_layers=4):
        super(RRDBBlock, self).__init__()

        # Define RRDB layers as a list
        self.layers = nn.ModuleList()
        for _ in range(num_layers):
            # Each layer consists of a 3x3 convolution and a ReLU activation
            self.layers.append(nn.Conv2d(channels, growth_rate, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1))
            self.layers.append(nn.ReLU(inplace=True))
            channels += growth_rate

        # 1x1 convolution at the end to fuse the outputs of all layers in the block
        self.conv1x1 = nn.Conv2d(channels, channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = x
        # Pass the input through each layer in the RRDB block
        for layer in self.layers:
            out = layer(out)
        # Fuse the output with the input through 1x1 convolution
        out = self.conv1x1(out)
        out = out + x  # Residual connection: add the original input to the output
        return out
    

# Define the ESRGAN model class
class ESRGANModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_rrdb_blocks=16, channels=64, growth_rate=32):
        super(ESRGANModel, self).__init__()

        # First convolutional layer to process 3-channel (RGB) input image
        self.conv_input = nn.Conv2d(3, channels, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)

        # RRDB blocks: stack multiple RRDB blocks to form the main part of the model
        self.rrdb_blocks = nn.ModuleList([RRDBBlock(channels, growth_rate) for _ in range(num_rrdb_blocks)])

        # Fusion block: 1x1 convolution to combine the outputs of all RRDB blocks
        self.conv_fusion = nn.Conv2d(num_rrdb_blocks * channels, channels, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding=0)

        # Upsampling layers: to upscale the processed image to the desired output resolution
        self.upsample = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(channels, channels * 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.PixelShuffle(2),  # PixelShuffle is used for upsampling by factor of 2
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(channels, channels * 4, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
            nn.PixelShuffle(2),
            nn.ReLU(inplace=True),
            nn.Conv2d(channels, 3, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1)  # Final 3-channel output
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.conv_input(x)  # Process input image with the initial convolutional layer
        residual = out  # Save the input image as a residual for later use

        # Pass the output through each RRDB block
        for rrdb_block in self.rrdb_blocks:
            out = rrdb_block(out)

        # Fuse the outputs of all RRDB blocks with a 1x1 convolution
        out = self.conv_fusion(out)
        out = out + residual  # Add the initial residual image to the fused output

        # Upsample the processed image to the desired output resolution
        out = self.upsample(out)

        return out
```

Unfortunately I get the following error: "KeyError: 'model_state_dict'". What am I missing?

Thank you in advance!

I expect the model to load properly so the sample image can be upscaled. I also tried to get rid of "KeyError: 'model_state_dict'" error by finding out the weight key manually by printing model_data.keys() but unfortunately I didn't get an unambiguous result.

Comment: print `model_data`

Comment: @PrajotKuvalekar The output is too long. It starts like this:```
OrderedDict([('model.0.weight', tensor([[[[ 0.0635,  0.1505, -0.1302],
          [-0.0817, -0.0222,  0.0601],
          [ 0.0315,  0.1476, -0.0574]],

         [[ 0.0752, -0.0627, -0.0195],
          [-0.1899, -0.1678, -0.1584],
          [-0.0056, -0.0209,  0.0305]],

         [[-0.1247, -0.0855,  0.1031],
          [ 0.2060, -0.0175,  0.1371],
          [-0.0376, -0.0331,  0.0955]]],


        [[[-0.1370, -0.1422, -0.0658],
          [-0.0691,  0.1849, -0.1106],
          [-0.1055, -0.1140, -0.1421]],
```

Comment: ll add the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way

```
model_data = torch.load(model_path, map_location=device)

# Create an instance of the ESRGAN model
model = ESRGANModel()  # Replace "ESRGANModel" with the correct name of your model class
model.load_state_dict(model_data,strict=False) # changed here
```

Comment: Hi, thank your for your help! Unfortunately I get the following error:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/minimal.py", line 24, in <module>
    model.load_state_dict(model_data)
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1604, in load_state_dict
    raise RuntimeError('Error(s) in loading state_dict for {}:\n\t{}'.format(
RuntimeError: Error(s) in loading state_dict for ESRGANModel:
 Missing key(s) in state_dict: "conv_input.weight", "conv_input.bias", "rrdb_blocks.0.layers.0.weight", "rrdb_blocks.0.layers.0.bias"```

Comment: hey  your keys in model definition are different from model dict... i ll edit my answer . check if it works

Comment: have editted the ans

Comment: Thank you once again! This time I got a different error message:

I posted the full message on pastebin because it's too long. 

https://pastebin.com/JkyS0MHp

I really appreciate your help! :)